# How to use multi-match query to get half search terms?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, match

I want to find names that start or have the phrase `man` in them. But I also want to query on different indexes.

So it should return all fields that have the term `man` in them such as `hoffman` last name, or anything that has the term in it.

How can I achieve this?

```
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "man",
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "last_name",
                "email"
            ]
        }
    }
}
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "man",
            "fields": [
                "billing.name",
                "billing.last_name",
                "billing.email"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search across multiple indexes, then you can use [`_index field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html), and for searching across multiple fields you can use `query_String` instead of a multi-match query.

```
GET /_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "_index": [
              "index-1",
              "index-2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*man*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```